# How do we distinguish between a finite clause and a non-finite clause?

Tags: meaning-in-context, subordinate-clauses

[Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/clauses-finite-and-non-finite)

> I had something to eat before leaving.
>
> I had something to eat before I left.

Do they mean the same, just differ in the sense that the former is a non-finite and the latter is a finite clause?

> **Having played** on computers all day, they **were** pale and hungry.

In this sentence, the introductory is non-finite and the latter is **finite**?

Comment: Yes, the meanings of the first two sentences are the same. Because the gerund _leaving_ does not show tense, the first is a non-finite clause. In the third sentence, both verbs, _played_ and _were_ show tense; both clauses are finite. (_Having_ is **not** the main verb in the first clause.)

Comment: In your 3rd example, the subordinate adjunct clause is non-finite, the VP "having played" being untensed: "having" and "played" are non-finite participles. The sentence as a whole is finite of course since the matrix verb "were" is tensed.